# Alias Column Values Dynamically on Condition with PHP

Tags: php, associative-array

I want to change column values on echo by condition. Working as a description of the column value. But I happen to echo only first satisfied clause on my work.

Heard associative arrays could make the workaround for this. I couldn't make that on my project's terms and also knowledge level. Here is the clear code of the function

```
function UFLAGAlias($productResult)
{    
while ($uflag = oci_fetch_assoc($result))
{ 

    $uflagc = $uflag["UFLAG"]; 


    if($uflagc == 0)
    {
        $uflagc= "Not Blocked";
        printf($uflagc);
    }

    else if($uflagc == 64)
    {
        $uflagc = "Blocked by system administrator";
        printf($uflagc);
    }

    else if($uflagc == 192)
    {
        $uflagc = "Blocked by system administrator\nBlocked for invalid logon"; 
        printf($uflagc);
    }

    else if($uflagc == 128)
    {
        $uflagc = "Blocked for invalid logon";
    }

    else
    {
        $uflagc = "";
    }
    return $uflagc;
}
}
```

On Echo

```
<?php
if (! empty($productResult)) {
foreach ($productResult as $key => $value) { 
?>
   <tr>
   <td><?php UFLAGAlias($productResult[$key]); ?></td>                
   </tr>
<?php
]
]

?>
```

So as I expect values to be output dynamically, all of the column values set as "Not Blocked". They have to be conditional. I believe this amount of code is enough as rest is private.

Comment: It's not clear what you're intending to have happen. Please provide an example of what is in `$productResult` and what the desired output of the resulting HTML code should be.

Comment: @fyrye $productResult retrieves fields from SAP's USR02(users) table. UFLAG field is keeping user's lock status as an integer index value. But they should not be numbers,but rather be shown as UFLAGAlias() function's met conditions.

Comment: Please update your question to include an example set of data and expected results should be, it doesn't have to be the source data, and you should remove any confidential data. See [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Right now we only have half the picture of what you are wanting to accomplish, and would require a lot of assumptions to determine what you're actually expecting to occur.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to fetch from a key since you have it upside down.

You need to fetch the result set and then -if needed- walk the resulting associative array.

```
<?php
function UFLAGAlias($uflag){
   $uflags = array( 0 => 'Not Blocked'
                  , 64 => 'Blocked by system administrator'
                  , 192 => 'Blocked by system administrator\nBlocked for invalid logon'
                  , 128 => 'Blocked for invalid logon'
                  );
   return isset($uflags[$uflag]) ? $uflags[$uflag] : '';
}

if (! empty($productResult)) {
   while( $row = oci_fetch_assoc($productResult) ):
?>
   <tr>
   <td><?echo UFLAGAlias($row['UFLAG']); ?></td>                
   </tr>
<?php
   endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: Yes, I needed to walk the associative array in that function. It works like charm :D Thanks